# How to convert a time_t type to string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, ctime

Is it possible to convert a `ltm->tm_mday` to string, please ?

I've tried this, but, this wouldn't work !

```
time_t now = time(0); 
tm *ltm = localtime(&now); 
String dateAjoutSysteme = ltm->tm_mday + "/" + (1 + ltm->tm_mon) + "/" + (1900 + ltm->tm_year) + " " + (1 + ltm->tm_hour) + ":" + (1 + ltm->tm_min) + ":" + (1 + ltm->tm_sec);
```

Comment: Check out `strftime()`. Not sure if there is a more C++ish way.

Comment: C++11: `std::stringstream buf; buf << std::put_time(ltm, "%d/%m/%I:%M:%S); std::string date = buf.str()`

Comment: To get it as milliseconds - note that this is technically "incorrect" because it assumes `time_t` is an integer, but it's the only quick way to do it...: `std::to_string(now);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all convinced that this is the best way to do it, but it works:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    std::stringstream date;
    date << ltm->tm_mday
         << "/"
         << 1 + ltm->tm_mon
         << "/"
         << 1900 + ltm->tm_year
         << " "
         << 1 + ltm->tm_hour
         << ":"
         << 1 + ltm->tm_min
         << ":"
         << 1 + ltm->tm_sec;
    std::cout << date.str() << "\n";
}
```

The `strftime()` function will do most of this work for you, but building up the parts of the string using a `stringstream` may be more generally useful.

Comment: Ok thank you, then, how can I convert `date` to str::string ?

Comment: @user3264174, Look in the answer.

Comment: @user3264174: The `str()` method returns a `std::string` from a `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `time_t` either using complex [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/), either simple [asctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/asctime/) functions to `char` array and then use corresponding `std::string` constructor.
Simple example:

```
std::string time_string (std::asctime (timeinfo)));
```

Edit:

Specifically for your code, the answer would be:

```
 std::time_t now = std::time(0);
 tm *ltm = std::localtime(&now); 
 char mbstr[100];
 std::strftime(mbstr, 100, "%d/%m/%Y %T", std::localtime(&t));
 std::string dateAjoutSysteme (mbstr);
```

Comment: can you, please just perform my example. Because, I couldn't understand what have you said :/

Comment: Do you mean `std::asctime` rather than `asctime`?

Comment: @KeithThompson At first I thought about simple `asctime` but looks like for C++ better to write `std::` one.

Comment: @Predelnik: My understanding is that `#include <time.h>` gives you `asctime` and may or may not give you `std::asctime`, whereas `#include <ctime>` gives you `std::asctime` and may or may not give you `asctime`. It's ugly, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @Predelnik, just apply it to my example like Keith Thompson, to se the result.

Comment: @user3264174 I added it as Edit to my post to not mess up the formatting but Keith Thompson's variant is actually better and more contemporary :D